# How to selectively remove tandem duplicate rows according to specific column value?

Tags: awk, grep

I am a green pea in command line text editing (like awk and grep). I have a table array and want to dereplicate rows according to values in column 4. I want to remove all rows containing the value 1 in columns 4 followed by same value in next row.

And here's a list of data,

```
k141    4797    2466    1
k141    4797    2466    2
k141    23474   11850   1
k141    27428   13800   1
k141    31736   15974   1
k141    35202   17751   1
k141    35202   17751   2
k141    35202   17751   3
k141    35202   17751   4
k141    35202   17751   5
k141    35202   17751   6
k141    35202   17751   7
k141    35202   17751   8
k141    35202   17751   9
k141    46266   23337   1
k141    54599   27445   1
k141    56753   28564   1
k141    56753   28564   2
k141    63661   32007   1
k141    71561   35988   1
k141    71561   35988   2
k141    72661   36561   1
k141    73579   37039   1
k141    84106   42358   1
k141    87251   43930   1
k141    88405   44516   1
k141    88405   44516   2
k141    88405   44516   3
k141    88405   44516   4
k141    89270   44939   1
k141    89270   44939   2
k141    89270   44939   3
k141    89270   44939   4
k141    93137   46825   1
k141    97378   48980   1
k141    97378   48980   2
```

My expected output is:

```
k141    4797    2466    1
k141    4797    2466    2
k141    35202   17751   1
k141    35202   17751   2
k141    35202   17751   3
k141    35202   17751   4
k141    35202   17751   5
k141    35202   17751   6
k141    35202   17751   7
k141    35202   17751   8
k141    35202   17751   9
(removal here)
k141    56753   28564   1
k141    56753   28564   2
(removal here)
k141    71561   35988   1
k141    71561   35988   2
(removal here)
k141    88405   44516   1
k141    88405   44516   2
k141    88405   44516   3
k141    88405   44516   4
k141    89270   44939   1
k141    89270   44939   2
k141    89270   44939   3
k141    89270   44939   4
(removal here)
k141    97378   48980   1
k141    97378   48980   2
```

Most methods online will remove all the following rows with values in column 4 equal to 1, such as awk `!($4 in a){a[$4]++; next} $4 in a` file

So I will be grateful if anyone may give suggestions on how it could be achieved.

Comment: Please reduce your example to a [mcve]. Whatever it is you're trying to do I'm sure we don't need to wade through 50 lines (or whatever that is) of input for you to be able to demonstrate it to us.

Comment: Thanks Ed. I will make the example more succinct next time.

Comment: You're welcome but why wait til next time? If you update it this time you **might** get more/better answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
awk '$4=="1"{o=$0;next;}{if(o)print o;o=0}1' file.txt
```

---

How does it work?

churn out duplicates, print the last duplicate, print all other lines.

```
$4=="1" { o=$0; next;}
```

IF column 4 EQUALS `1` THEN assign the entire line to variable `o` AND read the next line. (This basically churns out duplicates, saving the last one in `o`.)

```
{if(o)print o;o=0}
```

For lines that do not match the condition above, print the variable `o` (the last duplicate) and reset `o` to repeat this process.

`1`

print current line.

Comment: It works, thanks Rafeal. But would you mind breaking down how this command works?

Answer (score 0):

Using `uniq`, `man uniq`:

```
NAME
       uniq - report or omit repeated lines

       -f, --skip-fields=N
              avoid comparing the first N fields
```

Using `uniq`. `uniq` will pick the first duplicated value:

```
$ cat foo
1 1
2 2
3 2
4 3
$ uniq -f 1 foo
1 1
2 2
4 3
```

and apparently you want the last one so we need to use `tac` (`man tac`: *concatenate and print files in reverse*) with `uniq`:

```
$ tac file | uniq -f 3 | tac
k141    4797    2466    1
k141    4797    2466    2
k141    35202   17751   1
k141    35202   17751   2
```